# How to alert if max points reach, jquery

Tags: jquery

i got an evaluation form for faculty members, and i want to alert them when they already reached the maximum points required. Here is where the points are sum up.

```
<body>
<p class="submenu">1.0 Educational Qualification (Maximum Points 85pts)</p>
<span>Points generated:</span><input type="text" id="one-value" name="one-value"  class="textbox" value="" placeholder="Max points: 85pts" readonly /><BR>
</body>
```

here is my jquery

```
$("#one-value").validate()(function(){
   if ($("#one-value").val() == 85){
       alert('You have reach the maximum points required in this category');
   }else {

}
});
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Yes, but none of the ones i tried are working, i just want to alert the faculty that they had reached the max points when their points had reached the max

Comment: Then post what you've tried so we can see it.

Comment: there, i not sure if im using the correct codes, sorry

Answer (score 0):

bind a event to this item and check if the value overextended

```
$(document).on("change","#one-value",function(){
   if($(this).val()>=85) {
       alert("maximum Points 85 reached");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use the input event or the keyup event like this :

```
$('#one-value').bind('input', function(){
    if ($("#one-value").val()>=85){
        alert('Max points reached');
    }
});
```

OR you can use the keyup event also:

```
$('#one-value').bind('keyup', function(){
    if ($("#one-value").val()>=85){
        alert('Max points reached');
    }
});
```

The input event is triggered whenever there is any change to the input box value. The key up event is fired while entering a new value from the keyboard.